# Is it possible to add code coverage support to GAEUnit?

Tags: google-app-engine, code-coverage, coverage.py

One of the requested features for GAEUnit for over a year has been support for code coverage. Is it technically possible to add coverage support to GAEUnit so that after tests complete, a report could be generated of what modules were tested and what the coverage of each module was?

I can use coverage.py to launch the dev_appserver and produce a coverage report of a GAE python app but this requires local system configuration. One of the nice things about gaeunit is the ability to easily add it as an app to any python gae app so that anyone downloading the app can run the included tests. My ideal scenario would just extend gaeunit and add coverage data to the bottom of the report. So ideally the modification would run inside the dev_appserver as an app just like gaeunit does.

Is this technically possible? What approach would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coverage.py has a [programmatic API](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/api.html) that you can use.  I don't know anything about GAEUnit, but if you need help with coverage.py, get in touch.

Comment: Thanks Ned. I did not know about the coverage API. I have tried using the coverage API and I seem to have the basics working except for being able to print out the results. What parameters can I add to the report to get back details on all python modules that get accessed between start() and stop()? I'm currently getting a blank report with just the column headers. I'm trying to conclude with something like this.      self.response.out.write(cov.report())

Comment: Chris, send me an email (the address is on my website), and we can work through this in detail, then post the answer here once we've got it working.

Comment: Have you been successful in collecting code coverage for a GAE request?